# how to enable settings and developer section in umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

I'm newbie in Umbraco development. I would like to enable to "settings" and "developer" section in the dashboard. I don't know how to enable them. I checked in web.config file didn't find anything here. Any help is appreciated !

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in as a Admin in umbraco (Must be an admin account). Go to Users > [username] > select Settings and Developer in sections.